# Using res.render {objects} on client side

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, stringify

I know im not that good, and thats the reason of me posting here, but:

```
con.connect();

con.query('SELECT name, lname, rank FROM players LIMIT 1', function(err,rows, fields){
  if(err) throw err;
    result = rows;
    resultstringify = JSON.stringify(rows);
    console.log(result);
    console.log(resultstringify);
});

 con.end();
```

Node console gives me:

[ { name: 'FAKE', lname: 'FAKE', rank: 1 } ] 
[{"name":"FAKE","lname":"FAKE","rank":1}]

Then, i go for:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('players', 
{ title: "New page", result: result, resultstringify : resultstringify } );
});
```

then on client side i do

```
console.log("{{result}}");
```

and recieve [object Object]

```
console.log("{{resultstringify}}");
```

and recieve `[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;FAKE&quot;,&quot;lname&quot;:&quot;FAKE&quot;,&quot;rank&quot;:1}]`

```
console.log( JSON.parse("{{resultstringify}}"));
```

and recieve 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & (which is first letter [{"... )

I hope i've messed up with all the parse/stringify stuff, and its easy to fix, but i want to send and recieve it in a right way. Currently the best thing i can receive is

`[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;FAKE&quot;,&quot;lname&quot;:&quot;FAKE&quot;,&quot;rank&quot;:1}]`

but it does not look right

I did click all the links here, but still had to post this question.

**Update:**

Replace &quot with a single " helps:

```
arr = "{{resultstringify}}"; // call it
arr = arr.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'); //replace &quot with a single "
arr = JSON.parse(arr); //parse it
console.log(arr[0].name); //gives what you want
```

but i still cant figuire out where does &quot (and not " ) come from.

Answer (score 0):

Where ever I think you should try to display the content on html page once like

```
<div>{{result}}</div>
```

you are currently trying to display the content using console.log. The html displays correct data to me

Comment: Thanx for your reply. Yep, {{resultstringify}} does look normal inside div, while {{result}} is still [object Object]. 
But on JS side, how do i get acess to value of name, lname, rank? JSON.parse("{{resultstringify}}"); //returns Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

Answer (score 0):

Replace &quot with a single " helps:

```
arr = "{{resultstringify}}"; // call it
arr = arr.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'); //replace &quot with a single "
arr = JSON.parse(arr); //parse it
console.log(arr[0].name); //gives what you want
```